# Gcloud app module (subdomain) with ssl: certificate error

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, gcloud

Our Google Cloud app has a module, aka service, that is automatically added to the app's appspot.com domain as a subdomain. So our main app's url is:
**APPID.appspot.com**
And our module/service:
**MODULE.APPID.appspot.com**

We would like to make use of the nice way to force secure connections, by adding the following line in app.yaml:

```
secure: always
```

This works for our main app but the default certificate gives an error for the module. The certificate does not cover sub-sub-domains. The precise result is shown in the image below.

Is there any way to solve this with the app's code or the Gcloud interface? Or should I attach our own domain name to the app, and provide our own certificate in the system? If so, where should I add the certificate? I could not find this in the web interface.

[image]

Comment: use https://MODULE-dot-APPID.appspot.com/ url instead (notice `-dot-` instead of simple `.`)

Comment: Thanks for finding, that way will do for us!